Spring and virtual threads
I'm starting with JDK21 and virtual threads.
I'm using Spring Framework 6.1.12  with Spring Batch 5.1.2
I was using successfully a simple task executor like this:
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize"   value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize"    value="20" />
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>

To test virtual threads and JDK21, I changed to this:
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.VirtualThreadTaskExecutor">
    <constructor-arg name="threadNamePrefix" value="VIRTUAL-thread" />
</bean>

So, I have some questions about it:

Is this "migration" right?
Can I be sure it's using virtual threads? If I open VirtualThreadTaskExecutor, inside there is a VirtualThreadDelegate, in which all the methods raise exceptions.
Is there any "virtual threads pool" in Spring? Or, is it possible or it makes sense there are 20 virtual thread pools concurrently? I think virtual threads are designed not to be pooled, but this is a great change for me and I want to be pretty sure I'm doing in the right way.

So, in short, I have read wonderful things about virtual threads and performance, and I want to execute virtual threads in Spring and Spring Batch to test the performance in my software. If you have some guidelines, tips, etc. to migrate from platform threads to virtual threads, any help is very appreciated.


Sort of you can also use the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor which allows for some concurrency conttrol which the VirtualThreadTaskExecutor lacks. 2. Yes, 3. don't pool virtual threads that doesnt make sense. Also it will probably not improve your performance you might be able to do the same with less resources. If you are trying to improve calculations virtual threads aren't the right approach, only IO heavy loads.


@peeble-unit, thank you for your comment. If I'm right, in JDK21 virtual threads are enabled by default, and I'm not using Spring Boot.

@m-deinum, thank you for your comment. I will try your tips. It's obviously that platform threads improve my performance a lot (each customer calculates its expenses and generate its invoice). It's much better have 30 threads than 5. But, if, with the same performance, I use less resources, it's very good too.

Great answers so far so I am not going to add another one. However since you are using spring batch, I wanted to share with you a test suite that I have written to test virtual threads in Spring Batch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/b2a0d0343e4c3dbf1b9ac4734a9af97c2f6f0a33/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/samples/loom/VirtualThreadsSupportTests.java. While the suite is designed for correctness, you can use it with bigger datasets to test the performance improvements if any. I hope this helps.

Regarding your questions.

Sort of, you are probably better of using a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor which allows for a bit more configuration and control.

public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
  var taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
  taskExecutor.setVirtualThreads(true);
  taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(20); // based on your max poolsize
  return taskExecutor;
}


You are looking at the wrong one, there are actual 2 different ones as Spring is released as a multi-release jar. The code specific to JDK 21 is in a different directory and only loaded on JDK 21+ and will be loaded instead of the one you are looking at.

Don't cache Virtual threads as that doesn't make sense nor are they designed for that.


Finally temper your expectations, you might not get much of a performance boost but rather be able to do more with the same hardware in the same time. Due to more efficient thread usage. They aren't a magic solution. Virtual threads are designed to help with blocking IO tasks (it will then park) if your intend is to increase calculation heavy tasks you will be disappointed and probably even face performance degradation instead of increase.

The idea of using VirtualThreads(VT) is that they are lightweight (< 1 KB memory) and you can create as many of them. They are designed to not be pooled and they are build on top of Platform Threads(PT).
Is migration right?
You should consider your current code and your use case.
Is your old taskExecutor always used on I/O operations? Take into account that virtual threads are designed to work on blocking code like I/O operations, not for CPU-bound computation. So you must check that VT are used just on I/O operations (API calls, DB queries, File Reading and Writing...)
When a VT blocks in Java code, JVM unmounts the PlatFormThread to run another VT.
Additionally, it's important to understand the concept of pinning. Virtual threads (VT) are "pinned" to platform threads (PT) when they enter a section of C++ native code or a synchronized block. For example, if you create a custom library with blocking operations and use it through the Foreign Function & Memory (FFM) API (as introduced in JEP 454), or in a more common scenario, when a virtual thread is blocked using the synchronized keyword in the JVM, the JVM cannot dismount the virtual thread. This results in platform threads remaining occupied while virtual threads are left waiting, causing resource contention.
You can know if this is happening to you by adding -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full as JVM VM arg.
You can configure also other properties to tune your PTs with:
-jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism = The number of platform threads available for scheduling virtual threads. It defaults to the number of available processors.
-jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize   = The maximum number of platform threads available to the scheduler. It defaults to 256.
Take in mind that more PTs means more memory!
Were you using your old PTs with ThreadLocal to cache some data? For instance init an expensive operation. Could be a third party library for instance Jackson...
So for instance if you have this code you may have a problem on your migration:
synchronized void someOperation() {
   // SOME I/O OPERATION HERE
}

If you had this you should use ReentrantLock instead.
static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

void someOperation() {
  lock.lock();
  // SOME I/O OPERATION HERE
  lock.unlock();

Note* This will not solve the problem of VTs having to wait but at least they won't be pinned to the PTs
So in summary you not only have to check your own code but also third party libraries if they updated to Java21 with VT support.

Yes, your migration is quite right. It is one the most lightweight ways to move Spring non-Spring Boot application to virtual threads. VirtualThreadTaskExecutor is (virtual) thread-per-task non-pooling Executor. It does not implement, like ThreadPoolExecutor, ExecutorService interface and, consequentially, does not have things like shutdown and such, does not keep a track of spawned threads; instead it implements most simplest start-and-forget logic.

Can I be sure it's using virtual threads?

To check it call Thread.currentThread().isVirtual() inside of a method that is supposed to be executed on a virtual thread, for example ItemProcessor.process, and see if it returns true.

is it possible or it makes sense there are 20 virtual thread pools concurrently?

If you mean virtual thread executors (once again, VirtualThreadTaskExecutor you are going to use is not a pool), then yes, it is possible and does not carry much overhead as it is quite simple implementation. Generally speaking, it is not needed as single virtual thread executor will handle all submit requests without any loss of concurrency etc. It may make sense, however, to use multiple virtual thread executors for distinct thread prefixes, for example.
BTW, Spring Batch provides several examples on virtual thread usage.

I'll try to make a brief summary of this question.

Finally, I could test virtual threads in my SW. The performance didn't improve, but virtual threads are not specifically designed for speed boost.
For the same reason, it's not precisely right to talk about virtual threads pool.
In JDK 21 and Spring 6, you don't need to make any special config in your VM to get virtual threads.
In the answers, there are some interesting tips about VM options and Spring Batch testing.

I don't know if it's right to write this answer without an explicit, optimal and fitted solution to the initial problem. Anyway, I hope it helps.
Thank all the writers and commentators.

Thank you for the interesting question and the summary as well. Yes, for Spring Batch type of scenarios it is quite expected to not have dramatic increase in performance or decrease of memory usage. And virtual thread executor is not the best place where the benefits of virtual threads reveal themselves. In respect of jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.* parameters, which control underlaid ForkJoinPool instance, I also doubt they would play significant role unless your Steps are very many and quick and/or very CPU-intensive.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/spring-application.html#features.spring-application.virtual-threads and my personal experience, adding only 1 property spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true in your properties file is generally enough. From here, Spring will take care of managing threads.
For more advanced use cases, you may need to fine tune your parallelism or look into the type of work your threads are required to do. Virtual threads are suitable for more I/O operations.
By the way, do you really need XML based config now?

The OP does not use Spring Boot.
